# any alternate way to print global variable within function instead of :: operator

Tags: c++, global-variables

See the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int var = 20;
int main()
{
    int var =8;
    cout << "local var=" << var << "Global var =" << ::var << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Is there any other way to print the global variable, i.e. 20 within main where var has re-initialized?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want another way?

Comment: Do not use global variables in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant this :

```
int &p = ::var; // Using a reference

int var =8;

cout << "local var=" << var << "Global var =" << p << endl; //Play with p
```

Comment: any other way apart from int &p = ::var; without use of scope resolution operator.

Comment: @hims I don't think so

Answer (score 3):

There's no other way without modifying code outside your `cout` statement.  Trivially, you can obviously have `main` access `::var` indirectly - via another variable that's a reference or pointer to `var`, or copies the value of `var`, or a function returning any of those things etc..  (Unlike some other languages, there's no accessible meta-data carrying objects containing the global or calling context's stack frame / local variables etc..)

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been "reinitialized", the local declaration simply shadows the global one. You have to use the scope resolution operator.